# Postgres - Calculating group percentile for individual object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

My app has an assessments table. Each assessment scores people on a variety of levels, and is associated with a group. So something like this:

```
id: 'some-assessment',
user_id: 'some-user',
group_id: 'some-group',
overall_score: 98,
speed_score: 99,
vision_score: 97
```

When pulling an assessment from the database, I want to calculate statistics for each score relative to other scores for the same user or group as part of the returned object. As in, I want to return the following:

```
id: 'some-assessment',
user_id: 'some-user',
group_id: 'some-group',
overall_score: 98,
overall_score_user_percentile: 75, // ie, this score is in the 75th percentile of this users's other scores
overall_score_group_percentile: 60, // 60th percentile for group
speed_score: 99,
speed_score_user_percentile: 72,
speed_score_group_percentile: 63,
vision_score: 97,
vision_score_user_percentile: 71,
vision_score_group_percentile: 65,
```

I tried to do explore this by generating the following query (based off the use of `ntile` in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316562/nth-percentile-calculations-in-postgresql):

```
SELECT
  asmt.*,
  ntile(100) OVER (ORDER BY overall_score) AS overall_score_group_percentile
FROM
  assessments asmt
WHERE
  asmt.id='some-assessment'
```

> Note that this doesn't yet include logic that actually limits the `overall_score_group_percentile` to other assessments within the group.

Already, I'm running into an issue, which is that it appears that the `overall_score_group_percentile` calculates the percentile of the current assessment in the current group of assessments -- which is just the current assessment.

> In other words, I'm calculating the assessment's percentile within a list of only that one assessment itself. I'm *hoping* to calculate it within a wider specified list (either of the user's assessments, or the group's).

So I'm always getting `1` as the `overall_score_group_percentile`.

Any ideas how to calculate the percentile rank of this assessment vs some *other* set of assessments?

I've tried this as well, in an attempt to widen the comparison group to the full assessments table (before I try to narrow it by `group_id`):

```
SELECT
  asmt.*,
  ntile(100) OVER (SELECT overall_score FROM assessments ORDER BY overall_score) AS overall_score_group_percentile
FROM
  assessments asmt
WHERE
  asmt.id='some-assessment'
```

But no dice. I just get a syntax error.

Thanks! Any help sorting through this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a select within the over clause, you already have access to all columns, such as overall_score, within that table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `partition by`:

```
SELECT asmt.*,
       ntile(100) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY overall_score) AS overall_score_group_percentile
FROM assessments asmt
WHERE asmt.id = 'some-assessment';
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried, that, but it's still returning 1, I think because it's partitioning the list of 1 assessments by `group_id`. Is there a way to create a *different* set of assessments (one of all assessments with a given `group_id` and another with a given `user_id`) , and run the `ntile` function on those collections?