# Finding mean, standard deviation ,percentiles for all numeric variables in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, greenplum

I have 30 numeric numeric columns in a table .I want to find mean,std, percentiles for all the columns in table.I don't want to write all the column names manually like below

```
select date,
      avg(col1), stddev(col1),
      avg(col2), stddev(col2), 
from table name group by date;
```

Is there any way to find mean, std, percentiles for all the columns at once.

Comment: This answers most of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316562/nth-percentile-calculations-in-postgresql ... not sure about STDEV.

Comment: Others you will find here, [aggregate functions]:(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: you have to write the column names and the aggregate functions explicitly. no way around that in sql.

Comment: apache madlib supports postgresql. summary module should cover all statistics you want. http://madlib.apache.org/docs/latest/group__grp__summary.html

Comment: Greenplum or Postgres? They are very different (even though they share some common roots)

Comment: apache madlib supports both postgresql and greenplum

Answer (score 9):

You can simplify the logic using a lateral join:

```
select which, min(val), max(val), stddev(val), avg(val)
from t, lateral
     (values ('col1', col1), ('col2', col2), . . . 
     ) v(which, val)
group by which;
```

You still have to list the columns, but you only need to do so once in the `values` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL is a little bit trick in Greenplum.

Here is an example based on the instruction from https://www.pivotalguru.com/?p=266

```
$ psql postgres -c "create table foo (date date, c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);"
$ cat <<EOT >> /tmp/bar.sql
> select 'select ';
> select ' avg('  || attname || '), stddev(' || attname || '),' from pg_attribute
> where attrelid = 'foo'::regclass::oid and attnum > 0 and attname != 'date';
> select ' date from foo group by date;';
> EOT
$ psql -A -t  -f /tmp/foo.sql postgres | psql -a postgres
select 
 avg(c1), stddev(c1),
 avg(c2), stddev(c2),
 avg(c3), stddev(c3),
 date from foo group by date;
 avg | stddev | avg | stddev | avg | stddev | date 
-----+--------+-----+--------+-----+--------+------
```