# Postgresql: Count rows with same value but in different order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to count rows like in this table:

```
Product | Product2 | Value
Coke    | Lemon    |   3
Coke    | Potato   |   4
Coke    | Seven Up |   10
Lemon   | Coke     |   3
Lemon   | Meat     |   4
Pancake | Meat     |   23
Potato  | Coke     |   4
Seven Up| Coke     |   10
Meat    | Lemon    |   4
Meat    | Pancake  |   23
```

I must count the items but if they change order I still must count just once. 
So in this case I would have a result: 5. 
By the way, I already tried "where Product!= Product2" but this is not enough.

Can someone tell me what to do in this case? Thanks,

Comment: Can you please explain more ? 5 of what ?

Comment: For instance, we count a row :  Coke | Lemon |  3 . Then we must not count again Lemon | Coke | 3  , just because Lemon changed places with Coke. So applying this idea, considering this table, the result will be 5. Do you know how can I do it using SQL ? Thanks,

Comment: You didn't answer Houari's question: 5 what?  If you meant you want to count the number of *distinct products*, then (a) there are 6 of them, and (b) why not say that?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Distinct unordered pairs, i.e. distinct `(product, product1)` pairs where `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` are considered to be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Since you only have two columns, you can use [`greatest` and `least`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) to ignore the column order:

```
select greatest(product, product2) as a,
       least(product, product2) as b
from t
order by a, b
```

will give you:

```
Lemon    | Coke
Lemon    | Coke
Meat     | Lemon
Meat     | Lemon
Pancake  | Meat
Pancake  | Meat
Potato   | Coke
Potato   | Coke
Seven Up | Coke
Seven Up | Coke
```

Then toss in a `distinct` and `count`:

```
select count(
  distinct (
    greatest(product, product2),
    least(product, product2)
  )
)
from t
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/32111/6

Answer (score 2):

Based on [This array sorting function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870458/1216680), we can convert rows to an arrays, sort the array, and than select distinct values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sort (ANYARRAY)
RETURNS ANYARRAY LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest($1) ORDER BY 1)
$$;
```

and than:

```
SELECT count( distinct array_sort(array[product, product2]  ) ) FROM your_table
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This nicely generalizes to more than two product columns where the `greatest`/`least` trick doesn't work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/518b4/1