# Postgres GROUP BY Array Column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, group-by

I use postgres & have a table like this :

```sql
id   | arr
-------------------
 1   | [A,B,C]
 2   | [C,B,A]
 3   | [A,A,B]
 4   | [B,A,B]
```

I created a GROUP BY 'arr' query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, "arr" FROM "table" GROUP BY "arr"
```

... and the result :

```sql
total | arr
-------------------
 1    | [A,B,C]
 1    | [C,B,A]
 1    | [A,A,B]
 1    | [B,A,B]
```

BUT, since [A,B,C] and [C,B,A] have the same elements, so i expected the result should be like this :

```sql
total | arr
-------------------
  2   |   [A,B,C]
  2   |   [A,A,B]
```

Did i miss something (in query) or else? Please help me..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to create a separate function to do this.  It can all be done in a single statement:

```
select array(select unnest(arr) order by 1) as sorted_arr, count(*)
from t
group by sorted_arr;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/XAHUAV84636).

Answer (score 3):

[A,B,C] and [C,B,A] are different arrays even if they have the same elements they are not in the same position, they will never be grouped by a group by clause, in case you want to make them equivalent you'd need to sort them first.

On [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913368/sorting-array-elements) you have info abour sorting arrays.

You should do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, array_sort("arr") FROM "table" GROUP BY array_sort("arr")
```

After creating a sort function like the one proposed in there:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sort (ANYARRAY)
RETURNS ANYARRAY LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest($1) ORDER BY 1)
$$;
```

Comment: Wow its working. But, i still get an error if i JOIN it with other table. Let's say table1 and table2. I tried group it like this : array_sort("table1"."arr"), and got "ERROR: column "table1.arr" must appear in tht GROUP BY clause ......". can you explain why?

Comment: `SELECT count(id),ARRAY(SELECT unnest(arr) ORDER BY 1) from your_table group by 2` this will also produce the same result

Comment: Every column that is referenced must be grouped, if you are used table1.arr in your join clause you need to group it too, just add it after the first group part:

    ...GROUP BY array_sort("arr"), table1.arr

Comment: @w͏̢in̡͢g͘̕ed̨p̢͟a͞n͏͏t̡͜͝he̸r̴  It works as well! But how to use your solution in joined table? it will get "ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column "table1.arr" from outer query".

Comment: Which is the join you are trying to use?

Comment: @L. Amigo I have tried all of your solutions and work with my joined tables. Thanks a lot, sir! ;)