# ORDER BY [array] per ROW and after order per COLUMN

Tags: postgresql

I need some help to create a function to order:

- first the element inside an array;
- second order by the column;

I will try to explain through an example:

```
id |   names    |
- - - - - - - - -
1  |{ad, ab, cd}|
2  |{aa, ac}    |
3  |{cd, da}    |
```

The result of `ORDER BY names` should be

```
id |   names     |
- - - - - - - - -
2  | {aa, ac}    |
1  | {ab, ad, cd}|
3  | {cd, da}    |
```

I already tried this solution - [Sorting array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913368/sorting-array-elements) - but it doesn't work for me.

**UPDATE**: I think I get a point. I sorted inside the array but I don't change the order - I need an update on that. Probably I have to create a kind of virtual array (I don't know how to do that) and store the value which I sorted.

Comment: What exactly "didn't work"? Did you create the sort function suggested in the linked question?

Comment: Yes, I created this function 

'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sort (ANYARRAY)
RETURNS ANYARRAY LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest($1) ORDER BY 1)
$$;'

but it didn't sorting the array in the correct way. The elements inside the array is sorting random and not in ASC or DESC way.

Comment: Please show: your Postgres version (*always!*), your table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement), min/avg/max array length, cardinalities, what you tried.