# How to join two columns of the same table and count the number of rows

Tags: postgresql

Need help with the below scenario in PostgreSQL.

I need to match column A & column B and column B & column A in Table 1 and count the number of wires based on column A and column B.

Table 1

| Wire | Device From (Column A) | Device To (Column B) | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wire 1 | Device 1 | Device 2 | level 1 |
| Wire 2 | Device 1 | Device 2 | level 1 |
| Wire 3 | Device 2 | Device 1 | level 1 |

Output should look like

| No of Wire | Wires | Device from | Device To | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Wire 1, Wire 2, Wir3 3 | Device 1 | Device 2 | level 1 |

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem in a compact way, I converted your `device_from` and `device_to` columns to numbers (integers)

```
CREATE TABLE wiretable ( 
     wire text,
     device_from integer,
     device_to integer,
     level text);

INSERT INTO wiretable
         (wire, device_from, device_to, level)      
   VALUES('Wire 1', 1, 2, 'level 1'),
         ('Wire 2', 1, 2, 'level 1'), 
         ('Wire 3', 2, 1, 'level 1');
```

You need a way of comparing Device 1 and Device 2 so that `1,2` is the same as `2,1`. The only way I could think of to do it was by using an array and sorting. But to do array sorting, you have to install the intarray extension (`CREATE EXTENSION intarray;`) or do some tricks. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913368/sorting-array-elements) for how to sort arrays and/or install extension.

Basically you want to do a GROUP BY on two columns. I couldn't find anything like that in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY). So I put both columns in an array and GROUP BY that array. I have to do it in two steps.

```
  SELECT count(*), string_agg(wire, ', '),
         sort(array[device_from, device_to]) as combo, 
         level 
    FROM wiretable 
GROUP BY combo, level;
```

| count | string_agg | combo | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Wire 1, Wire 2, Wire 3 | {1,2} | level 1 |

That looks pretty good, but now we have to split `combo` back into two columns. We do this with a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/queries-with.html)

```
WITH foo AS (SELECT count(*), string_agg(wire, ', '),
                    sort(array[device_from, device_to]) as combo,  
                    level
               FROM wiretable
           GROUP BY combo, level)

SELECT foo.count, foo.string_agg as wires, 
       foo.combo[1] as "Device From",
       foo.combo[2] as "Device To", 
       foo.level
  FROM foo
```

which gives

| count | wires | Device From | Device To | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Wire 1, Wire 2, Wire 3 | 1 | 2 | level 1 |

Comment: The problem is Wire3 has to be Device 2,Device 1 not Device 1,and Device 2. In this case the query is not working. I want to check device_from-->device_to and device_to-->device_to then combine the wires.

Comment: Oops. I didn't read your Question carefully enough. I have rewritten my answer to make it insensitive to Device From/Device To

Comment: Sorry I am new to postgresql, this query is not working for me. ERROR:  function sort(text[]) does not exist
LINE 3:          SORT(array[device_from, device_to]) as combo, 
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883

Comment: You'll have to either install the `intarray` extension ('CREATE EXTENSION intarray;`) or follow the link in the answer for alternate ways to sort an array.

Comment: Thank you, can this be achieved by a direct select statement as I can use this select statement in my JPA

Comment: Yes. Follow the link in the answer for alternate ways to sort an array.